# Random Indy ResponseCode = -1 / EIdSocketError Socket Error # 0 exceptions

Tags: delphi, upload, delphi-2010, indy

I have a delphi code that basically upload files to remote **secure** server using **Indy 10.4.704**:

```
 IdHTTP                 := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
 try
    TheCompressor       := TIdCompressorZLib.Create(nil);
    TheSSL              := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);

    with IdHTTP do
    begin
         HTTPOptions     := [hoForceEncodeParams];
         AllowCookies    := True;
         HandleRedirects := True;
         ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;

         IOHandler       := TheSSL;
         Compressor      := TheCompressor;
    end;    // with

    // Get upload resume offset
    try
       IdHttp.Head('https://www.domain.com/my-file.bin');
       if (IdHttp.Response.ResponseCode <> 404) And (IdHttp.Response.ContentLength >= 0) then
          StartPos   := IdHttp.Response.ContentLength
       else
           StartPos  := 0;
    except
          StartPos   := 0;
    end;    // try/except

    // Upload File
    TheFile          := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead OR fmShareDenyWrite);
    RangeStream      := TIdHTTPRangeStream.Create(TheFile, StartPos, -1, True);
    try
       if (RangeStream.ResponseCode = 206) then
          IdHTTP.Post(https://www.domain.com/upload.php', RangeStream);
    finally
           RangeStream.Free;
    end;    // try/finally
 finally
        FreeAndNil(IdHTTP);
 end;    // try/finally
```

The problem is that **sometimes** the code fails with Indy throwing a **EIdSocketError Socket Error # 0** exception (**idHTTP.ResponseCode** is -1)

Given my crappy internet connection, I launched an EC2 windows instance and tested my code on it (the windows instance is running on the cloud, so I assume connection *is not* a problem), yet I got the same issue!

The error seems to be random, sometimes upload works, sometimes not. I debugged with TidLogFile, all I could find is something like this:

```
Stat Connected.
Sent 4/26/2012 4:18:42: POST /app/upload.php...
Sent 4/26/2012 4:18:42: <uploaded_file_data_here>
Stat Disconnected.
```

Anyone knows what's causing this/how to fix this?

**EDIT**

I [traced the exception back to TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL](http://derp.co.uk/02511). I googled a lot, it seems that it's not an SSL error.

Comment: Have you tried to use the debugger and locate the Indy source line which raises the exception? I would also try a newer version of Indy to see if the exception message is different, as 'socket error 0' is not a standard socket error number, maybe it means 'no connection to server'

Comment: @mjn: I edited my post, this is really strange as the connection is supposed to be *almost perfect* (at least it shouldn't give me that many socket #0 errors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please upgrade to the latest Indy 10 version, which is **10.5.8 r4743**.  SSL-related issues with Error Code 0 were fixed over a year ago.

Comment: Thank you so much Remy! I deleted the old Indy version (including the old dcu, bpl, etc... files) re-build everything and now I'm **not** able to see the error when running the tests on EC2/Windows (ie. upload files from EC2 to S3). However, I **still see the same errors** when uploading from my machine...

Comment: The fact that the `ResponseCode` is -1 means that either the response is malformed or the error is occurring before `TIdHTTP` even receives the first line of the response. Can you see the response correctly in a packet sniffer like Wireshark or Fiddler? What does the call stack look like in the debugger when the error is raised?

Comment: [Stack is here](http://derp.co.uk/aba7f) and [TidLogFile content is here](http://derp.co.uk/279a1), but I'm overwhelmed by Winshark's output I can't even decide which output is related to the error, thought I found some `[TCP Retransmission] Ignored Unknown Record` and `Secure Sockets Layer Ignored Unknown Record` entries

Comment: OK, I took the time to inspect the code a bit more, it seems that this issue is **closely related** to [my last question about cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439511/global-thread-safe-cookies-manager-with-indy). When I call `GlobalCookieManager.CookieCollection.AddCookie()` in `TUploadThread.NewCookie()`, many times the [internal cookies list contains a extra, broken cookies](http://pastebin.com/BiJCnFb0), but **only the first two cookies are valid**!

Comment: The presence of rubbish cookies causes an exception when calling `TextIsSame()` in `TIdCookies.AddCookie()`, because (starting from the 3rd cookie in `FCookieList`) `LOldCookie` is assigned some crappy data & the text compare fail. This causes the IdHTTP.Post() to fail (sometimes with `ResponseCode = -1`, sometimes `ResponseCode = 200` but POST still fail because of the exception mentioned)

Comment: Hopefully I explained well the issue, is there a way to avoid this exception? This is causing unnecessary POST/re-upload, making my app's upload process painfully slow. I'm essentially using [the code that you posted here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10439820/1165880)

Comment: `AddCookie()` takes ownership of the cookie that is passed to it. So you end up with multiple `TIdCookieManager` objects referring to the same physical cookie objects. That would account for cookies getting trashed. I see two possible solutions: have `OnNewCookie` call `AddCookie()` with a copy of `ACookie` instead of `ACookie` directly, or call `AddServerCookie(ACookie.ServerCookie)` instead of `AddCookie()`.

Comment: Thank you very much Remy! I'll continue to monitor this but my initial tests suggests that this has fixed the issue!