# Global, thread safe, cookies manager with Indy

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-2010, indy

My Delphi 2010 app uploads stuff using multi-threading, uploaded data is POSTed to a PHP/web application which requires login, so I need to use a shared/global cookies manager (I'm using **Indy10 Revision 4743**) since TIdCookieManager is not thread-safe :(

Also, server side, session id is automatically re-generated every 5 minutes, so I **must** keep both the global & local cookie managers in sync.

My code looks like this:

```
TUploadThread = class(TThread)
// ...

var
   GlobalCookieManager : TIdCookieManager;

procedure TUploadThread.Upload(FileName : String);
var
   IdHTTP           : TIdHTTP;
   TheSSL           : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
   TheCompressor    : TIdCompressorZLib;
   TheCookieManager : TIdCookieManager;
   AStream          : TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
begin
     ACookieManager := TIdCookieManager.Create(IdHTTP);

     // Automatically sync cookies between local & global Cookie managers
     @TheCookieManager.OnNewCookie := pPointer(Cardinal(pPointer( procedure(ASender : TObject; ACookie : TIdCookie; var VAccept : Boolean)
     begin
          OmniLock.Acquire;
          try
             GlobalCookieManager.CookieCollection.AddCookie(ACookie, TIdHTTP(TIdCookieManager(ASender).Owner).URL{IdHTTP.URL});
          finally
                  OmniLock.Release;
          end;    // try/finally

          VAccept := True;
     end )^ ) + $0C)^;
     // ======================================== //


     IdHTTP         := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
     with IdHTTP do
     begin
          HTTPOptions     := [hoForceEncodeParams, hoNoParseMetaHTTPEquiv];
          AllowCookies    := True;
          HandleRedirects := True;
          ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;

          IOHandler       := TheSSL;
          Compressor      := TheCompressor;
          CookieManager   := TheCookieManager;
     end;    // with

     OmniLock.Acquire;
     try
        // Load login info/cookies
        TheCookieManager.CookieCollection.AddCookies(GlobalCookieManager.CookieCollection);
     finally
            OmniLock.Release;
     end;    // try/finally

     AStream         := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;

     with Stream.AddFile('file_name', FileName, 'application/octet-stream') do
     begin
          HeaderCharset  := 'utf-8';
          HeaderEncoding := '8';
     end;    // with

     IdHTTP.Post('https://www.domain.com/post.php', AStream);
     AStream.Free;
end;
```

But it doesn't work! I'm getting this exception when calling AddCookies()

> Project MyEXE.exe raised exception class EAccessViolation with message
>   'Access violation at address 00000000. Read of address 00000000'.

I also tried using assign(), ie.

```
 TheCookieManager.CookieCollection.Assign(GlobalCookieManager.CookieCollection);
```

But I still get the same exception, usually here:

```
 TIdCookieManager.GenerateClientCookies()
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: What in the world are you doing with the OnNewCookie assignment?  When I see multiple layers of pointer casts, wrapped around an anonymous method, ending with something like `end )^ ) + $0C)^;`, I get a bit nervous.

Comment: I agree it's not the best code, but as I wrote in code, the OnNewCookie is there to keep both local & global Cookie managers in sync (and, as far as I can tell, the issue is not with the OnNewCookie event)

Comment: I agree with @MasonWheeler. The `OnNewCookie` event expects a non-static method of an object instance, not an anonymous procedure.  `TIdCookieManager` is going to pass a hidden `Self` pointer to the event handler, but your anonymous parameter is not accounting for that, so the rest of the event parameters are going to be messed up.

Comment: Thank you guys, I converted to a normal method, but I'm still getting exceptions in AddCookies(), last one happened in the line that reads `FRWLock.BeginWrite;` in this procedure `TIdCookies.LockCookieList(AAccessType: TIdCookieAccess): TIdCookieList;`

Comment: Where are you instantiating and freeing the `GlobalCookieManager` object?  Since it is being used globally, you should be doing so in the unit's `initialization` and `finalization` blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Responding to the comment:

> Thank you guys, I converted to a normal method, but I'm still getting
>   exceptions in AddCookies(), last one happened in the line that reads
>   FRWLock.BeginWrite; in this procedure
>   TIdCookies.LockCookieList(AAccessType: TIdCookieAccess):
>   TIdCookieList;

If your error is an Access Violation with `Read of address 00000000`, that's got a very specific meaning.  It means you're trying to do something with an object that's **nil**.

When you get that, break to the debugger.  If the error's taking place on the line you said it's happening on, then it's almost certain that either `Self` or `FRWLock` is **nil** at this point.  Check both variables and figure out which one hasn't been constructed yet, and that'll point you to the solution.

Comment: Given the code that has been shown, most likely the `GlobalCookieManager` object has not been instantiated prior to being used.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use an anonymous procedure for the `OnNewCookie` event.  Use a normal class method instead:

```
procedure TUploadThread.NewCookie(ASender: TObject; ACookie : TIdCookie; var VAccept : Boolean);
var
  LCookie: TIdCookie;
begin
  LCookie := TIdCookieClass(ACookie.ClassType).Create;
  LCookie.Assign(ACookie);
  OmniLock.Acquire; 
  try 
    GlobalCookieManager.CookieCollection.AddCookie(LCookie, TIdHTTP(TIdCookieManager(ASender).Owner).URL); 
  finally 
    OmniLock.Release; 
  end;
  VAccept := True;
end;
```

Or:

```
procedure TUploadThread.NewCookie(ASender: TObject; ACookie : TIdCookie; var VAccept : Boolean);
begin
  OmniLock.Acquire; 
  try 
    GlobalCookieManager.CookieCollection.AddServerCookie(ACookie.ServerCookie, TIdHTTP(TIdCookieManager(ASender).Owner).URL); 
  finally 
    OmniLock.Release; 
  end;
  VAccept := True;
end;
```

Then use it like this:

```
procedure TUploadThread.Upload(FileName : String); 
var 
  IdHTTP           : TIdHTTP; 
  TheSSL           : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL; 
  TheCompressor    : TIdCompressorZLib; 
  TheCookieManager : TIdCookieManager; 
  TheStream        : TIdMultipartFormDataStream; 
begin 
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil); 
  try
    ...
    TheCookieManager := TIdCookieManager.Create(IdHTTP); 
    TheCookieManager.OnNewCookie := NewCookie;

    with IdHTTP do 
    begin 
      HTTPOptions     := [hoForceEncodeParams, hoNoParseMetaHTTPEquiv]; 
      AllowCookies    := True; 
      HandleRedirects := True; 
      ProtocolVersion := pv1_1; 

      IOHandler       := TheSSL; 
      Compressor      := TheCompressor; 
      CookieManager   := TheCookieManager; 
    end;    // with 

    OmniLock.Acquire; 
    try 
      // Load login info/cookies 
      TheCookieManager.CookieCollection.AddCookies(GlobalCookieManager.CookieCollection); 
    finally 
      OmniLock.Release; 
    end;

    TheStream := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create; 
    try
      with TheStream.AddFile('file_name', FileName, 'application/octet-stream') do 
      begin 
        HeaderCharset  := 'utf-8'; 
        HeaderEncoding := '8'; 
      end;

      IdHTTP.Post('https://www.domain.com/post.php', TheStream); 
    finally
      TheStream.Free; 
    end;
  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Remy, but I still have the same issue...see [my comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439511/global-thread-safe-cookies-manager-with-indy#comment13477337_10439511)

Comment: It turns out that `AddCookie()` takes ownership of the cookie that is passed to it. So you will end up with multiple `TIdCookieManager` objects referring to the same physical cookie objects. That would cause cookies to get trashed. I see two possible solutions: have `OnNewCookie` call `AddCookie()` with a copy of `ACookie` instead of `ACookie` directly, or call `AddServerCookie(ACookie.ServerCookie)` instead of `AddCookie()`.

Answer (score 3):

If I had to guess, I'd say your problem is in here somewhere:

```
 // Automatically sync cookies between local & global Cookie managers
 @TheCookieManager.OnNewCookie := pPointer(Cardinal(pPointer( procedure(ASender : TObject; ACookie : TIdCookie; var VAccept : Boolean)
 begin
      OmniLock.Acquire;
      try
         GlobalCookieManager.CookieCollection.AddCookie(ACookie, TIdHTTP(TIdCookieManager(ASender).Owner).URL{IdHTTP.URL});
      finally
              OmniLock.Release;
      end;    // try/finally

      VAccept := True;
 end )^ ) + $0C)^;
```

I'm not sure what the `$0C` magic number is there for, but I bet all those casts are there because you had a heck of a time getting the compiler to accept this.  It gave you type errors saying you couldn't assign the one thing to the other.

Those type errors are there for a reason!  If you hack your way around the type system, things are very likely to break.  Try turning that anonymous method into a normal method on TUploadThread and assign it that way, and see if it doesn't work better.

Comment: Thank you Mason, see [my comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439511/global-thread-safe-cookies-manager-with-indy#comment13477337_10439511)