# (Indy) TIdHTTP EIdSocketError Socket Error # 0 exceptions when downloading files

Tags: delphi, download, delphi-2010, indy

I have this delphi code that basically **download** files from a secure server (using Indy build 10.5.8 r4743 if I'm not mistaken):

**The problem is:** I'm getting random "Socket Error # 0" exceptions that I couldn't get fix or even understand:

`Project MyProject.exe raised exception class EIdSocketError with message 'Socket Error # 0`

[Stack is here](http://dug.im/04607), pascal code is:

```
IdHTTP            := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
TheSSL            := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
TheCompressor     := TIdCompressorZLib.Create(nil);
TheCookieManager  := TIdCookieManager.Create(IdHTTP);

try SetupWebComponents(IdHTTP, TheSSL, TheCompressor, TheCookieManager); except end;

TheCookieManager.OnNewCookie := MainForm.SyncNewCookie;

// Go!
Stream            := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
   IsError        := False;
   try
      with IdHTTP do
      begin
           OnWork                := MainForm.IdHTTPWork_Download;
           try
              try
                 IsNewFile       := (Not FileExists(LocalFile));
                 if IsNewFile then
                    TheFile      := TFileStream.Create(LocalFile, fmCreate)
                 else
                     // File already exist, resume download
                     TheFile     := TFileStream.Create(LocalFile, fmOpenReadWrite);

                 DoExit          := False;

                 // Use [ Request.Referer ] it to pass VersionGUID to Work event (to record download progress in db)
                 Request.Referer := VersionGUID;
                 repeat
                       // Get resume byte
                       if IsNewFile then
                       begin
                            ResumeByte := 0;
                            IsNewFile  := False;
                       end
                       else
                           ResumeByte  := GetResumeByteFromDB();

                       if FileExists(LocalFile) then
                       begin
                            // File already exist, resume download
                            DoExit     := (ResumeByte >= TheFileSize);
                            TheFile.Seek(ResumeByte, soFromBeginning);
                       end;

                       // Save ResumeByte, it will be used to record download progress in db & eventually use it to resume downloads)
                       IdHTTP.Tag      := ResumeByte;

                       Request.Range := IntToStr(ResumeByte) + '-';

                       Get(TheURL, TheFile);
                       IsError         := (Not (ResponseCode in [200, 206])) OR (Pos('login', URL.Document) <> 0);

                       // Break if there's any error (to allow retrying later in a clean fashion)
                       if IsError then
                          Break;
                 until DoExit;

                 Disconnect;
              except
                    if (ResponseCode = 404) then
                    begin
                         // File doesn't exist, get out
                         Result        := False;
                         Exit;
                    end;
              end;    // try/except
           finally
                  FreeAndNil(TheFile);
           end;    // try/finally
      end;    // with
   except
         IsError  := True;
   end;    // try/except
finally
       Stream.Free;
end;
```

I [posted a similar question some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326810/random-indy-responsecode-1-eidsocketerror-socket-error-0-exceptions), but that was regarding **upload, not download**. The code was fixed since then with the kind help of SO members, and the same code (used to deal with cookies, re-login, etc...) is being used now so I assume the problem is really in the download procedure shown above

**Can someone please take a look at this tell me what I'm doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like with your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326810/random-indy-responsecode-1-eidsocketerror-socket-error-0-exceptions), you should upgrade to a more recent version, if possible, and verify the problem still occurs before then asking for help.  The current version is **10.5.9 r4861**.

Comment: Thank you Remy. FWIW, Indy download page is confusing, just a reminder to myself / anyone in the same position, the **real** download link to [the latest build is here](http://indy.fulgan.com/ZIP/)...I'll try with the latest build & see if I still have this issue, thanks!

Comment: OK, I just upgraded and now I'm getting this exception: `Project blabla.exe raised exception class EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError with message 'Error connecting with SSL.
error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure'.` I'm not sure what this means, my SSL is valid, I'm certain.

Comment: IMHO, the download page is not confusing, it is accurate and straight forward, it just takes a few links to find the actual download link, that's all. There is a lot of information to convey to users before they download.

Comment: You are getting an SSL handshake error, so no, your SSL setup is not valid.  Double-check your settings.

Comment: Remy: `IdHTTP.Post(https_url)` works just fine so I assume SSL is fine...I'm no expert here, what do you mean by `SSL setup is not valid`?

Comment: Plus, I'm pretty sure didn't change anything in the setup / DLLs. I just updated the library paths in Delphi, opened & compiled the packages and then did a build all in my project.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself: "I just upgraded and now I'm getting this exception ... IdHTTP.Post(https_url) works just fine". Which is it? Either `IdHTTP.Post(https_url)` works or it fails with an exception, you can't have it both ways. Or ar eyou suggesting that `IdHTTP.Post(https_url)` works but `IdHTTP.Get(https_url)` fails? That would not make sense, either, since they both share the same connection code.

Comment: My apologies, I should have been more explicit: `idHTTP.Post(https_url)` works just fine, but the code in my original post that uses `idHTTP.Get(https_url)` fails with SSL error mentioned above. [Stack is here](http://derp.co.uk/8a47e)

Comment: I tried again, clearly `idHTTP.Post()` works with HTTPS urls, while `idHTTP.Get` fails. The .GET method calls an HTTPS URL that redirects to another domain (https://mysite.com/ to https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/file.bin), maybe this is it? (ps. HandleRedirects is set to true). Any suggestion?

Comment: A redirection to another URL could very well be an issue, yes. Perhaps that other URL has more restrictive SSL requirements than the original URL did. I've never encountered a situation where an HTTPS url redirected to a different domain, but I would think `TIdHTTP` can handle that in general. Since it is an SSL handshake issue, I would ask the domain admins about their SSL requirements.

Comment: This used to work just fine in rev. r4743, the first domain is mine, the other belongs to Amazon.com, and I'm not sure what do you mean by "SSL requirements". My domain's (original idHTTP request goes there) [SSL certificate basic info is here](http://dug.im/e3e81), and [amazonaws.com's SSL certificate basic info is here](http://dug.im/fd2ce)

Comment: OK, I just realized that .Get works just fine with SSL **if there is no redirection**. Just in case, I posted [idHTTP initialization code here](http://pastebin.com/g8cCmeEx). It looks like the latest build either broke .GET & redirected requests or is incompatible with my code.

[IdFileLog output is here](http://pastebin.com/YWXApmbn), and [SSL OnStatusInfo event output is here](http://pastebin.com/hkpgzPG6), clearly Indy is having issues with the 2nd domain (amazonaws.com).

Comment: The only change made to `TIdHTTP` since r4743 is how it parses HTML `<meta>` tags. Nothing related to SSL. However, there have been changes to `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` since r4743 to add support for TLS 1.1 and 1.2, so I suppose something related to that might have broken something in your code. Double-check your SSL settings, make sure they are actually what you are expecting on each connection that `TIdHTTP` makes. You might also try using Wireshark to look at the actual SSL handshake data to see what the "sslv3 alert handshake failure" is actually complaining about.

Comment: Remy I'm not sure what you mean by "SSL settings". I posted all the indy code that I use here, and the **only SSL-related code** that I use is this `ASSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);` and this `IdHTTP.IOHandler := ASSL;` nothing else (I'm pretty sure). Regarding WireShark, I [captured the output](http://dug.im/15f5f) but I don't know what to expect/how to read this, all it says it that the handshak failed...

Comment: The default values of the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` properties are not always the best choice to use for every server.  Chances are, you need to tweak them a little. Obviously Amazon does not like the property values you are currently using. Either the SSL/TLS version is unacceptable, or you need to add/change the certificates that are used, or something.

Comment: OK, I played a bit with the ssl settings, it seems that `ASSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvSSLv23];` fixed the problem, and strangely, I can't reproduce the original bug, I'll keep testing until I confirm this, but I assume the problem is fixed for now. Again, thank you  very much for your help Remy!

Comment: `sslvSSLv23` is a wildcard that allows the SSL handshake to dynamically negotiate the highest available SSL/TLS version, so that likely means that your domain and Amazon are using different SSL/TLS versions from each other.