# Login to craigslist to retrieve account page using Delphi and Indy and SSL

Tags: delphi, http, delphi-2010, indy

I am trying to log into craigslist using Delphi, and retrieve my account page (in order to gather a listing of all my posts)

However, I can't seem to get the login to work, what Am I doing wrong?

```
function TfrmMain.Login: string;
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Request: TStringList;
  Response: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Result := '';
  try
    Response := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      Request := TStringList.Create;
      try
        Request.Add('op=login');
        Request.Add('redirect=http://newyork.craigslist.org/');
        Request.Add('login=' + myEmail);
        Request.Add('password=' + myPassword);
        IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
        try
          IdHTTP.AllowCookies := True;
          IdHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
          IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
          IdHTTP.Post('https://accounts.craigslist.org/login', Request, Response);
          Result := IdHTTP.Get('https://accounts.craigslist.org/');
        finally
          IdHTTP.Free;
        end;
      finally
        Request.Free;
      end;
    finally
      Response.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

I get a exception class EIdIOHandlerPropInvalid with message 'IOHandler value is not valid' on the line:

```
IdHTTP.Post('https://accounts.craigslist.org/login', Request, Response);
```

thanks

Comment: As first, you're not using SSL IO handler.

Comment: @Johnny, get a copy of the OpenSSL library [`from here`](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/), from the archive extract the `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` files, so that they'll be visible to your project output (so e.g. into the same directory as your project output is) and modify your code [`this way`](http://pastebin.com/AFAhEjHW). You were missing SSL IO handler, which must be used when working with SSL secured sites.

Comment: TLama, I think we are almost there. on the same line that I got my exception in my original post, it is now throwing a socket error #0

Comment: I'm sorry. You buried your problem description in a code block. I didn't read all the code, so I didn't see your question. Mjn has fixed that for you.

Comment: Your question should be updated to indicate that the program now throws a socket error #0

Comment: @JohnnyHolmes I don't understand your reaction to Rob's comment. That comment is polite and helpful. View it in the light of the original version of the post, the one that you posted, in which the error message was not visible without scrolling through the code block. You need to develop a slightly thicker skin to ask questions on SO. If people ask for more information, try and understand their point of view.

Comment: @TLama - im using Delphi 2010 and I get the error.

Comment: @JohnnyHolmes I'm not down voting! I've answered loads of your questions. I am trying to help you. So is Rob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [(Indy) TIdHTTP EIdSocketError Socket Error # 0 exceptions when downloading files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233648/indy-tidhttp-eidsocketerror-socket-error-0-exceptions-when-downloading-files) and the suggestions in the comments. It looks like you should upgrade to a more recent version of Indy.

Comment: Actually I jumped to conclusion. That didn't throw and error, and it did return HTML, but it return the login page back instead of the accounts page. I am re-opening a new question