# IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL Delphi Socket Error #0

Tags: sockets, delphi, ssl

I have been reading a lot about Delphi, POST command og SSL.

My problem is this:

I have to contact this site:
https://payment.architrade.com/cgi-bin/confirmtransact.cgi

Explanation can be found here:
http://tech.dibspayment.com/D2/FlexWin/API/Status_functions/confirmtransactcgi

Doing this in Chrome or firefox returns 0. Just as the explanation says.

Some 3 years ago I made an implementation to call this. 
I made it in Delphi 2010.

This has been running without flaws for 2½ years. 
The last 6 months I get **Socket Error #0** almost instantly after calling.
I happens more and more aften, and today it is constant.

At this point our customer can't use the routine because of this.

In my program, I use this:

```
HttpPosten: TIdHTTP;
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
```

The code is like this:

```
procedure TForm6.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FejlKode: String;
begin
  Try
    Memo1.Lines.Clear;
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Starter på test...');
    Memo2.Lines.Clear;

    FejlKode := HttpPosten.Post('https://payment.architrade.com/cgi-bin/confirmtransact.cgi',Memo2.Lines);

    HttpPosten.Disconnect;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Resultat:');
    Memo1.Lines.Add(FejlKode);
  Except
    on E: exception do
    Begin
      FejlKode  := e.Message;
      Memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
      Memo1.Lines.Add('FEJL (2):');
      Memo1.Lines.Add(FejlKode);
    End;
  End;
end;
```

And at the moment I end up in the except part constantly.

I need suggestions to where to look after this?
Is this within Delphi, Indy, SSL, Server, Internet, Firewall or where should I look?

Someone says I should upgrade Indy to newest version. 
But it has been running with these components for 2½ years without problems. 
If I uograde, I would like to know, which version I have now. Where do I find that information?

So - I really need some advice.

Regards Michael

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/10326810/960757

Comment: I do not agree, that it is a duplicate...

I have read that post, and it did not help me. Here I believe they try to download a file. I just try to "talk" to a webadress. And it has been working for a long time...

Comment: But rereading the post, makes me believe I should update Indy

Comment: ...hence I only posted the link. About the time when your code worked. It is possible that they changed (updated) the server (if I got it right that it's not yours) and they prepared conditions for that client issue. `</conspiracy-theory>` In any case, I would update.

Answer (score 1):

> The last 6 months I get Socket Error #0 almost instantly after calling. I happens more and more aften, and today it is constant.

I am not able to reproduce the error using the latest version of Indy (10.6.2.5274 at the time of this writing) and the exact code you have showed.  The `Post()` call succeeds with an HTTP `200 OK` response and a body payload of `0`, just like you are getting in Chrome/Firefox.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: -
Date: Tue, 19 May 2015 17:05:35 GMT
Connection: close
X-Server-Name: payment27
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
P3P: CP="NON DSP CURa CUSa OUR NOR STA"
Content-Type: text/plain
Connection: close
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000

0
```

> Someone says I should upgrade Indy to newest version. But it has been running with these components for 2½ years without problems.

You should always use the latest, when feasible.  For instance, socket error #0 was addressed a long time ago.

> If I uograde, I would like to know, which version I have now. Where do I find that information?

You can right-click on any Indy component in the Form Designer at design-time.  Or read the `Version` property of any Indy component at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

I also got this error for DELPHI 2010 and INDY 10.5.5 when trying to post to a https website.
I solved it by setting **hoKeepOrigProtocol** property to **true** for idHTTP1 component. Then the "socket error #0" never came back.

I know it is an old topic, but it is visible in google. Some people stil reading it.

Comment: We got the same issue on Delphi 2010 and INDY 10.5.5. This resolved the issue for us