# How to work around the Socket Error # 0 bug in Indy 10.5.5?

Tags: delphi-2010, indy, indy10

As has been [reported before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326810/random-indy-responsecode-1-eidsocketerror-socket-error-0-exceptions) and fixed in a subsequent release, there is a bug in Indy 10.5.5 that causes `EIdSocketError` to be raised even for successful requests.

For now I am stuck with this version. Are there any changes I can make to the code below to avoid the problem? I'm looking for a solution that stops the exception from being raised, rather than catching it every single time. A link to a ticket describing the exact problem would already be helpful - I haven't been able to find more info on it other than that it has been fixed quite a while ago.

```
LHTTPClient.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(LHTTPClient);
LHTTPClient.Request.BasicAuthentication := True;
LHTTPClient.Request.Username := 'username';
LHTTPClient.Request.Password := 'password';
LHTTPClient.Post('https://...', LRequestStream, LResponseStream);
```

Comment: There is nothing you can change in your code to fix this.  The fix has to be applied inside of Indy's internals, in the way `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` reports errors to `TIdIOHandler` and round-trip back into `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` for processing and exception raising. If you cannot upgrade, you will have to do a diff between your version and the latest version and apply the same fix to your version.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Too bad the problem is so deep and there is no way around it. If you'll post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.